# Another beautiful arctan integral $\int_{1/2}^1 \frac{\arctan\left(\frac{1-x^2}{7 x^2+10x+7}\right)}{1-x^2} \, dx$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, definite-integrals, special-functions

Do you think we can express the closed form of the integral below in a very nice and short way?
As you already know, your opinions weighs much to me, so I need them!

Calculate in closed-form

$$\int_{1/2}^1 \frac{\arctan\left(\frac{1-x^2}{7 x^2+10x+7}\right)}{1-x^2} \, dx.$$

I'm looking forward to your precious feedback!

*Mathematica* tells us the closed form is

$$\frac{1}{4} i \text{Li}_2\left(\frac{1}{5}+\frac{2 i}{5}\right)+\frac{1}{4} i \text{Li}_2\left(\frac{2}{15}+\frac{2 i}{5}\right)-\frac{1}{4} i \text{Li}_2\left(\frac{1}{5}-\frac{2 i}{5}\right)-\frac{1}{4} i \text{Li}_2\left(\frac{2}{15}-\frac{2 i}{5}\right)-\frac{1}{4} i \text{Li}_2\left(\frac{1}{4}+\frac{i}{8}\right)+\frac{1}{4} i \text{Li}_2\left(\frac{1}{4}-\frac{i}{8}\right)-\frac{1}{4} i \text{Li}_2\left(\frac{1}{10}+\frac{3 i}{10}\right)+\frac{1}{4} i \text{Li}_2\left(\frac{1}{10}-\frac{3 i}{10}\right)+\frac{1}{4} i \text{Li}_2\left(\frac{1}{4}+\frac{i}{12}\right)-\frac{1}{4} i \text{Li}_2\left(\frac{1}{4}-\frac{i}{12}\right)-\frac{1}{4} i \text{Li}_2\left(\frac{4}{15}+\frac{8 i}{15}\right)+\frac{1}{4} i \text{Li}_2\left(\frac{4}{15}-\frac{8 i}{15}\right)+\frac{1}{4} \log (4) \tan ^{-1}(6)-\frac{1}{4} \log (4) \tan ^{-1}(9)+\frac{1}{4} \log (4) \tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{6}\right)-\frac{1}{4} \log (4) \tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{9}\right)-\frac{1}{4} \log (9) \tan ^{-1}(2)+\frac{1}{4} \log (9) \tan ^{-1}(3)-\frac{1}{4} \log (9) \tan ^{-1}(6)+\frac{1}{4} \log (9) \tan ^{-1}(9)-\frac{1}{4} \log (9) \tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{3}{55}\right)+\frac{1}{4} \log (16) \tan ^{-1}(2)-\frac{1}{4} \log (16) \tan ^{-1}(3).$$

Comment: can you control it by hand?

Comment: @chris isnt the evaluated result pure real? cant get the (i) part.

Comment: You have a strange concept of beauty.

Comment: Please show your effort.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Substituting $x\to\frac{1-x}{1+x}$ is usually a first reaction of mine. Here it works surprisingly well: the integral is equivalent to 
$$I=\int_{1/2}^1 \frac{\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{1-x^2}{7 x^2+10x+7}\right)}{1-x^2} \, dx=\frac12\int_0^{\frac13}\frac{\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{x}{x^2+6}\right)}{x} dx.$$

Integrating by parts, 
$$I=-\frac12\ln3 \tan^{-1}\left(\frac{3}{55}\right)-\frac12\int_0^{\frac13} \frac{6-x^2}{x^4+13x^2+36}\,\ln x \, dx$$

This looks managable. We can decompose $\displaystyle \, \frac{6-x^2}{x^4+13x^2+36}=\frac{2}{x^2+4}-\frac{3}{x^2+9} $

so that 
$$\int_0^{\frac13} \frac{6-x^2}{x^4+13x^2+36}\,\ln x \, dx=2\int_0^{\frac13} \frac{\ln x}{x^2+2^2}\,dx-3\int_0^{\frac13}\frac{\ln x}{x^2+3^2}\,dx$$

Now these integrals may also be done by partial fraction (whence emerge the complex stuff) and the antiderivative of the remaining parts is easily found in terms of logarithms and dilogarithms..

So the logarithm and $tan^{-1}$ cancel at the end, leaving:

> $$ I=\frac12\Im\operatorname{Li_2}\left(\frac1{9i}\right)-\frac12\Im\operatorname{Li_2}\left(\frac1{6i}\right)$$

*Edit*

The final cancellation and Chris' comment below suggest a detour to the integration by parts and partial fractions decomposition:

We just notice that $\displaystyle \tan^{-1}\left(\frac{x}{x^2+6}\right)=\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)-\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{x}{3}\right)$, whence

$$I=\frac12\int_0^{\frac13}\frac{\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{x}{x^2+6}\right)}{x} dx=\frac12\int_0^{\frac13}\frac{\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)-\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{x}{3}\right)}{x}dx\\=\frac12\int_0^{\frac16}\frac{\tan^{-1}x}{x}dx-\frac12\int_0^{\frac19}\frac{\tan^{-1}x}{x}dx=\frac{1}{2}\operatorname{Ti}_2\left(\frac{1}{6}\right)-\frac12\operatorname{Ti}‌​_2\left(\frac{1}{9}\right).$$

Comment: (+1) Very nice. I didn't notice that the substitution $x\mapsto \frac{1-x}{1+x}$ makes things so easier.

Comment: That proves that the final closed form just depends on $\log(3),\arctan\left(\frac{3}{55}\right), \text{Li}_2\left(\pm\frac{i}{6}\right)$ and $\text{Li}_2\left(\pm\frac{i}{9}\right)$.

Comment: true, that leaves only the dilogarithms of $\pm\frac{i}{6}$ and $\pm\frac{i}{9}$, nice. Time to downvote Maple and Mathematica's outputs? :D

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio huh, that's nice.. I wonder if the dilogs simplify too?

Comment: After cancelation, it remains $$\frac{1}{2}\left(\operatorname{Ti}_2\left(\frac{1}{6}\right)-\operatorname{Ti}_2\left(\frac{1}{9}\right)\right)$$ I think.

Answer (score 5):

Exploiting integration by parts, the problem boils down to computing:

$$ \int_{1/2}^{1}\left(\log(1+x)-\log(1-x)\right)\left(\frac{3}{5x^2+8x+5}-\frac{4}{5x^2+6x+5}\right)\,dx $$
and by partial fraction decomposition that is equivalent to computing:
$$ I_{\pm}(\zeta)=\int_{1/2}^{1}\frac{\log(1\pm x)}{x-\zeta}\,dx $$
with $\zeta\in\left\{-\frac{3}{5}-\frac{4i}{5},-\frac{3}{5}+\frac{4i}{5},-\frac{4}{5}-\frac{3i}{5},-\frac{4}{5}+\frac{3i}{5}\right\} $. We may check that:
$$ \int \frac{\log(1+x)}{x-a} = \log(1+x)\log\left(1-\frac{1+x}{1+a}\right)+\text{Li}_2\left(\frac{1+x}{1-a}\right) $$
holds by differentiation to compute the closed form of the original integral in terms of dilogarithms and products of logarithms only.

Answer (score 1):

It can be easily checked by differentiation that:
$${\large\int}\,\frac{\arctan\left(\frac{1-x^2}{7 x^2+10x+7}\right)}{1-x^2} \, dx=\\
\frac i4\left[\vphantom{\Large|}\operatorname{Li}_2\left(\left(-\tfrac12+\tfrac i6\right)(x-1)\right)-\operatorname{Li}_2\left(\left(-\tfrac12-\tfrac i6\right)(x-1)\right)\\
\,+\operatorname{Li}_2\left(\left(-\tfrac12-\tfrac i4\right)(x-1)\right)-\operatorname{Li}_2\left(\left(-\tfrac12+\tfrac i4\right)(x-1)\right)\\
\!\!\!\!\!\!+\operatorname{Li}_2\left(\left(\tfrac12+i\right)(x+1)\right)\,\,\,\,\,\,-\operatorname{Li}_2\left(\left(\tfrac12-i\right)(x+1)\right)\\
\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,+\operatorname{Li}_2\left(\left(\tfrac12-\tfrac{3i}2\right)(x+1)\right)\,\,\,-\operatorname{Li}_2\left(\left(\tfrac12+\tfrac{3i}2\right) (x+1)\right)\right]\color{gray}{+C}$$
This enables us to evaluate a definite integral over any interval.

If you are only interested in real values of $x$ then the antiderivative can be simplified to:
$$\frac12\Im\left[\vphantom{\Large|}\operatorname{Li}_2\left(\left(\tfrac12+\tfrac{3i}2\right)(x+1)\right)-\operatorname{Li}_2\left(\left(\tfrac12+i\right)(x+1)\right)\\
\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,+\operatorname{Li}_2\left(\left(\tfrac i4-\tfrac12\right)(x-1)\right)-\operatorname{Li}_2\left(\left(\tfrac i6-\tfrac12\right)(x-1)\right)\right]\color{gray}{+C}$$

Comment: Good to know (and I like the form you got). Thanks! (+1)